# Aggregate two data frame by duplicated rows only

Tags: r

I used aggregate function to sum up both duplicated and unique rows and find the common column mean in two data frame(df & nm) i.e.

```
df
User    Apple   Cherry  Kiwi    Lemon
A       208      71     129     58
B       81       69     142     53
C       164      212    175     200
D       125      73     51      214
E       205      123    46      75
F       53      215     40      38

nm
User    Lemon   Cherry  Apple   Kiwi
A        161     57      27      38
B        26      153     57      45
C        39      153     219     86
D        47      155     139     61

kl = aggregate(.~User, data=rbind(df, nm[, match(colnames(df), colnames(nm))]), FUN=mean)
```

It shows output of both duplicated and unique rows.

```
kl
User    Apple   Cherry  Kiwi    Lemon
A       117.5    64     83.5    109.5
B       69       111    93.5    39.5
C       191.5    182.5  130.5   119.5
D       132      114    56      130.5
E       205      123    46      75
F       53      215     40      38

But  wanted output of only duplicated rows i.e. unique rows should be removed.

 kl
    User    Apple   Cherry  Kiwi    Lemon
    A       117.5    64     83.5    109.5
    B       69       111    93.5    39.5
    C       191.5    182.5  130.5   119.5
    D       132      114    56      130.5
```

How can I do this using above formula.

I tried to find this answer but everywhere both duplicated and unique example was shown.

Kindly provide the solution!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to subset the rows of 'df' before `rbind`ing

```
aggregate(.~User, rbind(df[df$User %in% nm$User,], nm), FUN = mean)
#   User Apple Cherry  Kiwi Lemon
#1    A 117.5   64.0  83.5 109.5
#2    B  69.0  111.0  93.5  39.5
#3    C 191.5  182.5 130.5 119.5
#4    D 132.0  114.0  56.0 130.5
```

Or if we are using `match`

```
aggregate(.~User, rbind(df[match(df$User, nm$User, nomatch = 0),], nm), FUN = mean)
```

If we are only interested in the common `User`s, yet another option is `intersect`

---

In the OP's code, `match` was used to subset the columns while the columns were the same in both the datasets.

Comment: Thanks akrun!! It works like charm. My dataset is large is there any another method to this same acivity faster.